# How to change transaction isolation level globally?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

How can I change the default transaction isolation level for the database?

The [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-set-transaction.html) show how to change it per transaction and per session - but not how to alter the default for the database or cluster.

In MySQL the operation is

```sql
SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
```

Is there an equivalent for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 9):

Per the contents of [this book indexed by google](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZsxPDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA303&lpg=PA303&dq=alter+database+default_transaction_isolation&source=bl&ots=BDPISch4v8&sig=ACfU3U0umSTKXli9HQ1Lq-6RkxExQr-xCg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf2YzozajqAhWLKs0KHT3iC8YQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=alter%20database%20default_transaction_isolation&f=false)

> One can change the whole default database isolation level to SERIALIZABLE as follows
>
> ```sql
> ALTER DATABASE <DATABASE NAME> SET DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_ISOLATION TO SERIALIZABLE ;
> ```

So for read committed, for example, one can do:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE <db name> SET DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_ISOLATION TO 'read committed';
```

and you can confirm this with

```
SELECT current_setting('transaction_isolation')
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `default_transaction_isolation` parameter appropriately, either in `postgresql.conf` or with `ALTER SYSTEM`. After reloading, this will apply to the whole cluster.

You can also use `ALTER DATABASE` or `ALTER ROLE` to change the setting for a database or user only.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `read committed` is set globally in **PostgreSQL** as shown below:

```
postgres=# SHOW default_transaction_isolation;
 default_transaction_isolation
-------------------------------
 read committed
(1 row)
```

So, to change it to `read uncommitted` globally, run **the query below** first:

```sql
            -- Database name
                  ↓
ALTER DATABASE postgres SET DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_ISOLATION TO 'read uncommitted';
```

Then, you need to log out and log in again otherwise `read committed` is not changed to `read uncommitted` globally:

```
postgres=# exit
```

```
psql -U postgres
```

Now, `read committed` is changed to `read uncommitted` globally as shown below:

```
postgres=# SHOW default_transaction_isolation;
 default_transaction_isolation
-------------------------------
 read uncommitted
(1 row)
```

In addition, `read uncommitted` has the same characteristics of `read committed` in **PostgreSQL** different from other databases so in short, `read uncommitted` and `read committed` are the same in **PostgreSQL**.

> PostgreSQL's Read Uncommitted mode behaves like Read Committed.